# replace None with Null, in place

Tags: python, csv, null

I have a requirement to drop my test results into a csv for reporting.  In my python test code when I don't have a value, my variables are filled in the python way with None.

I have been asked to replace these with "Null" in the CSV for the reporting tool.  I am thinking this is easy and has probably be solved a hundred times.

Here is the code I came up with:

```
   for field in (TestCase.productUnderTest,TestCase.versionUnderTest,TestCase.name,TestCase.results,TestCase.lastTestEnd,TestCase.parent,TestCase.level):
        if field == None: 
             field = 'Null'

    ME.csvoutput.write("%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s\n" % (TestCase.productUnderTest,TestCase.versionUnderTest,TestCase.name,TestCase.results,TestCase.lastTestEnd,TestCase.parent,TestCase.level))
```

Unfortunately that only changes the field within the scope of the for loop.  How can I change it for the scope of the write statement.

(I would be quite happy to just write "Null" and leave my variables unchanged, but I can work either way.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
result = [TestCase.productUnderTest,TestCase.versionUnderTest,TestCase.name,TestCase.results,TestCase.lastTestEnd,TestCase.parent,TestCase.level]
result = map(lambda x:x==None and 'Null' or str(x), result)
ME.csvoutput.write(",".join(result)+'\n')
```

Comment: In case there are numbers, you have to apply 'str' to x if it is not None, to allow 'join' to work properly.

Comment: `map` and `lambda` are deprecated

Comment: @vartec: In that case, we could use simple list comprehension or generator. for eg. [x==None and 'Null' or str(x) for x in result]

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly.  Of course if map and lambda are deprecated, what is the more modern solution?

Comment: @SkipHuffman: `[('Null' if x is None else str(x)) for x in result]`

Comment: Thanks Petr, that works even better.  (Plus I just had a scope change, now the PM wants '' instead of 'Null', so that was an easy change.)

Answer (score 0):

To keep your code, you can try:

```
for field_name in ('productUnderTest','versionUnderTest','name','results','lastTestEnd','parent','level'):
    if getattr(TestCase, field_name) is None:
        setattr(TestCase, 'Null')
```

I suggest to look at the [csv](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html) module.

Comment: I'll look at csv module.  I had forgotten about it.  (Used in the past, but not recently.)

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

```
fields = [str(field) or "Null" for field in (TestCase.productUnderTest,TestCase.versionUnderTest,TestCase.name,TestCase.results,TestCase.lastTestEnd,TestCase.parent,TestCase.level)]
ME.csvoutput.write("%s\n" % ",".join(fields))))
```

Or, even more powerfull: use generator object instead:

```
fields = (str(field) or "Null" for field in (TestCase.productUnderTest,TestCase.versionUnderTest,TestCase.name,TestCase.results,TestCase.lastTestEnd,TestCase.parent,TestCase.level))
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use method Pandas fillna:

```
from pandas import DataFrame
DataFrane.fillna(value='NULL', inplace=True)
```

Example

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(csv_file)
df.fillna(value='NULL', inplace=True)
```